# Support for SSL termination for an Azure VM exposing a http endpoint

Tags: azure, networking

I have an azure vm that exposes a web site in addition to a lot of custom software running on it. The web site currently runs on port 8000 and supports only http.

I would like to give customers the option of connecting over Https but I also have very little ability to change things on the VM.

Could i spin up an application gateway and solve the problem that way i.e. have the Application Gateway expose a HTTPS endpoint and turn around and route traffic to the VM and back. Would appreciate specifics on  how to get this working

I tried doing this and encountered a 502 Bad Gateway. Haven't had much luck debugging this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use an application gateway.

Use an NSG to block traffic from the internet to that VM. As we all know, http isn't secure.

Spin up an application gateway. Standard V2 will be fine. Connect it to the same VNET as the VM.

Configure a Listener, Configure it with a https/ssl/tls certificate. Associate it with the hostname of your application. Just use 'Single' host type if you're just using one hostname.

Configure a Backend pool. Point it to your VM.

Configure a backend setting. This tells the gateway how connect to your backend pool. For your situation it'll be http. You can't decide if you need to override the backend hostname (i.e. if you want to access via site-a.com but the VM is listening for hostname site-b.net)

Lastly, configure a Rule. This is the glue between your listener and backend pool.